# How to make rows of table clickable in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, datatables, click, core-ui

I am using the CoreUI admin theme for VueJs.

I am trying to make a table via CoreUI. Now I have to make the rows of the table Clickable.

Any idea as to how I can do that?

Here is there documentation on Tables:
https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/table.html#cdatatable-api
In there CDataTable API under events , they have row-clicked events. I just don't know how to use it.

Any sorts of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add event listner like this
please focus on `@row-clicked="rowClickHandler"` and method `rowClickHandler` in methods

```
    <template>
      <CCardBody>
        <CDataTable
          :items="items"
          :fields="fields"
          @row-clicked="rowClickHandler"  // <== focus here
        >
          ... Rest of the code
        </CDataTable>
      </CCardBody>
    </template>
    <script>

export default {
  name: 'AdvancedTables',
  data () {
    return {
      items: [],
      fields: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    rowClickHandler ((item, index, column name, event) {
    // whatever you want to do
    },
   ... other methods
  }
}
</script>
```